# Mocking Protected Constructor

Tags: java, junit4, powermockito

I want to mock *super*() call that has **protected contructor**.

For this purpose i use "PowerMockito.suppress"
but it isn't work (the code call super constructor and it throw runtimeException).

How to mock super call(), so it doesn't do anything.

```
    public class FooClass {

        public void someMethod(){
            String arg1 = "arg1";
            Integer arg2 =  123;
            ExtendedClass extendedClass = new ExtendedClass(arg1, arg2);
        }
    }

    public class SuperClass {
         protected SuperClass(String arg1, Integer arg2) {throw new RuntimeException();}
    }

    public class ExtendedClass extends SuperClass{

        public ExtendedClass(String arg1, Integer arg2){
            super(arg1, arg2);
         }
    }

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    @PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*", "com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.*", "javax.net.ssl.*"})
    @PrepareForTest({SuperClass.class})
    public class TestClass extends TestCase{

        @InjectMocks
        FooClass fooClass = new FooClass();

        @Test
        public void test(){
            PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(SuperClass.class, String.class, Integer.class));
            fooClass.someMethod();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think, i asked question correctly but sorry i do a fault in my code, it is             PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(**SuperClass** .class, String.class, Integer.class)); In this direction, i fix my code according to this comment. suppress operation must be on super class not child class.

Comment: Thank you all answers, you are right that to mock super class constructor mock(super class has also protected constructor), we mock child class suppress and use PrepareForTest annotation at child class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Prepare ExtendedClass for Test and not SuperClass.

change

```
 @PrepareForTest({SuperClass.class})

 PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(SuperClass.class, String.class, Integer.class));
```

to

```
 @PrepareForTest({ExtendedClass.class})

 PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(ExtendedClass.class, String.class, Integer.class));
```

Comment: Do you try that after changing code "PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(SuperClass .class, String.class, Integer.class));" .

Comment: Sorry, The question isn't this. Your answer is that suppress public constructor of ExtendedClass.

Comment: try to debug this code. And see. The call goes to ExtendClass constructor but not to SuperClass constructor. I guess that is what you want

Comment: No, My purpose is the code  go  into extended class and suppress SuperClass. This does not supply my requirement.

Comment: not sure what is the difference between what i said and you said. Its the same thing... With the code i gave, that code goes to the ExtendedClass Constructor and not to SuperClass Constructor(supressed). anyways good luck

Answer (score 2):

You test successfully passed on my machine:

[image]
Which versions of powermock and mockito do you use?

Here are my:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The root cause of your issue as @pvpkiran already wrote that you have to Prepare ExtendedClass for Test and not SuperClass

**Updated:**
Have a look at this link [Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior#suppress-super-class-constructors](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior#suppress-super-class-constructors)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TestParentConstructor.ExtendedClass.class})
public class TestParentConstructor {

    @Before
    public void init() {
        suppress(constructor(SuperClass.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        FooClass fooClass = new FooClass();
        fooClass.someMethod();
    }

    public class FooClass {
        public void someMethod(){
            String arg1 = "arg1";
            Integer arg2 =  123;
            ExtendedClass extendedClass = new ExtendedClass(arg1, arg2);
        }
    }

    public class SuperClass {
        protected SuperClass(String arg1, Integer arg2) {throw new RuntimeException();}
    }

    public class ExtendedClass extends SuperClass{
        public ExtendedClass(String arg1, Integer arg2){
            super(arg1, arg2);
            System.out.println("Hello from Extended!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mockito = 1.10.19, PowerMockito = 1.6.4

Comment: The same successful result with your versions

Comment: Do you change my last edit that i mention on my comment

Comment: @ramazankul I've updated my answer with another example, check please